# Postfix - how to forward emails containing a certain user to one account

Tags: postfix, virtualization

I've searched the net and can find lots of examples doing this the other way but not this way.

We have a Postfix mail relay serving machines on multiple domains.

We want to redirect all root emails to one specific root mailbox.

So:

- root@something.com -> root@properdomain.com
- root@another.com -> root@properdomain.com
- root@yetanother.com -> root@properdomain.com
- etc
- etc

I've tried adding the following to /etc/postfix/virtual but it does not work:

/root@(.*)/ root@properdomain.com

vi /etc/postfix/main.cf:
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
postfix reload

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you are going to use regular expressions in your virtual table, it needs to be mapped as a `pcre:` table, not a `hash:` table.

Comment: Perfect - that worked a treat, many thanks NickW!!! It says I have to wait 10 mins before accepting this as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!